# SQL - How to use a column in a select statement without specifying it in the group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am trying to run this query but it fails:

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, 
 cast(collect(coalesce(product_type, decode(product_description,null,'DESCR' || '-' product_description) as my_type) as product_type,
 decode(product_source_location, null, 'NO_SOURCE', product_source_location)
from products
group by p.product_id, p.product_name
```

It fails because `product_source_location` is not part of the group by clause.

I dont want to include `product_source_location` in to the `group by` clause as the result i get back becomes incorrect. Is there a way i can use `product_source_location` in the decode function as shown above without having to include it in the group by clause?

Interestingly i am using product_type in the coalesce function and it does not force me to include `product_type` in the group by clause.

Comment: This SQL has an extra comma in it. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @Ciaran The error is [1]: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression on the product_source_location

Comment: You are missing some right parentheses : 5Left, 3 right.

Comment: @shahkalpesh collect is a group function, hence the need for group by

Comment: @tbone: Thanks. The comment is removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
coalesce(max(product_source_location), 'NO_SOURCE')
```

The complicated collect statement is correct, because collect is an aggregation function.  The final decode is using a column not mentioned in the `group by` clause.  This fixes the problem by wrapping `max()` around it.

And, you can do this using `decode()`:

```
decode(max(product_source_location), NULL, 'NO_SOURCE', max(product_source_location))
```

But I encourage you to learn the more standard `coalesce()` function and `case` function.

Comment: But wouldn't max(column_name) select the maximum value from that column instead of the value from the current row?

Comment: @ziggy . . . Yes it would.  But, you don't want every different value.  If you did, you would put it in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Ok i tried it and it works but i dont understand why it works.
Is it because the value of product_source_location will be the same (for the group) so max() will just pick one?

Comment: @ziggy in that case you could use `min` or `average`. Yes it will only pick one if they are the same.

Comment: @ziggy . . . I don't know the structure of the data.  It is quite possible that product_source_location is the same for each row, in which case it does not matter if you use `max()`, `min(), or put it in the `group by` clause.  You can find out by doing a query such as `select product_id, count(distinct product_source_location) . . . `.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just use DISTINCT? Like so:

```
select DISTINCT p.product_id, p.product_name, 
 cast(collect(coalesce(product_type, decode(product_description,null,'DESCR' || '-' product_description) as my_type) as product_type,
 decode(product_source_location, null, 'NO_SOURCE', product_source_location)
from products
```